# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request on Android when trying to upload image via Http Put

Tags: android, http-put

I a a new comer to Android development. I am trying to upload an image through HTTP PUT from an android device. When i run the following code, my response shows HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request error.

Any help to solve this issue will be appreciated. Here is the code snippet i have been using.

```
File file = new File(imageAdd);
HttpPut job = new HttpPut("http://api.abcd.com/");
FileEntity entity = new FileEntity(file, "image/jpeg");
entity.setChunked(true);
job.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(host,job,credContext);
```

Comment: ask you server what is wrong with your request

Comment: (also, that's not a put, as the name of the object suggests)

Comment: I do not host the server. So, I do not know how to debug what is wrong with my request. The API also provides examples using curl. The one I am trying to reproduce is                                                                                                                                                                                                                               curl --digest -u userName:password "http://api.abcd.com/" --form image_file=@"image.jpg" -X PUT